# Compile multiple sources using CSharpCodeProvider

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to compile several external files using CSharpCodeProvider? I'm now just compile a string. I want to create a hierarchy of `.cs` files and then compile them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [FromFileBatch method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codecompiler.fromfilebatch.aspx), it accepts an array of files.

Comment: Thanks man! You're the one, every time you save me. Thanks. I put your name in my program, I'll contact you soon when my 2d engine was done.